# Vue.js - Best way to emit event from sibling component to sibling?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a parent component which has child A and child B, child B has Child C inside it.

So I need to trigger an event from child A to Child C, what is the best way to to this?

Or maybe is there a way to watch for a change in the store.state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between sibling components in VueJs 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616167/communication-between-sibling-components-in-vuejs-2-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a store, I assume Vuex, just watch the store state change. To do that, you need to bring that piece of the store into your component with a computed property. Then watch the computed property.

```
{
    computed:{
        myProp(){
            return this.$store.state.myProp
        }
    },
    watch:{
        myProp(){
            //myProp changed
        }
    }
}
```