# How to show tab data from sibling component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I'm new in vuejs, I want to show tab data from from sibling component, below is my code. Please help!!

I could toggle the tab but unable to show data from sibling component

`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <section>
      <div>logo</div>
      <tabs></tabs>
      <div>right menu</div>
    </section>
    <tabs-data></tabs-data>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    'tabs': {
      template: '<div><a href="#" v-on:click="checkClass()" v-bind:class="{ active: ist1 }">tab1</a><a href="#" v-on:click="checkClass()" v-bind:class="{ active: ist2 }">tab2</a></div>',
      data () {
        return {
          ist1: true,
          ist2: false
        }
      },
      methods: {
        checkClass: function () {
          this.ist1 = !this.ist1
          this.ist2 = !this.ist2
        }
      }
    },
    'tabs-data': {
      template: '<section><p v-if="ist1">Tab Data 1</p><p v-else>Tab Data 2</p></section>'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`

Comment: See this question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616167/communication-between-sibling-components-in-vuejs-2-0

Comment: Appreciate your early response, if you could share the jsfiddle.net example, it would be life saver for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "**bridge**" in parent for events. I don't know if it is a good way

```
events : {
    'bridge'( e, ...args ) {
        // $broadcast would not trigger the events in parent, add $emit if you want parent itself can also detect the event.
        this.$emit( e, ...args );
        this.$broadcast( e, ...args ); 
   }
}
```

and dispatch event in components with the bridge

```
this.$dispatch( 'bridge', 'real-event-name', params );
```

Comment: Appreciate your early response, if you could share the https://jsfiddle.net/ example, it would be life saver for me.