# How can give notice to the brother level component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a single-page application.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

the `body` is a `router-view`, I can route in it, it can route to `a, b, c` components.

you see, if in `b` component, `b` and `header` are the same level components.

How can I in `b` component to give notice to `header` component?

---

the case is:

in `header`, it can popup a modal to login, then in its data have `is_login`, `user_data` properties, through those `header` can display user info and other buttons. if I login in the header, I can easily store the `is_login` and `user_data` to Cookie or localStorage.

but if I am login by the modal of `b` component, I can store the `is_login`
 and `user_data` to Cookie or localStorage too, but how can I let the `header` know the `is_login` and `user_data` is updated in Cookie or localStorage? then it can update the view.

Comment: you can use bind data or `this.$emit()`

Comment: them are not the parent-child components, them are the same level.

Comment: you can use event bus or vuex to do what you want,I recommend that you use vuex to manage your states.

Comment: I wrote a long answer on [Vue communication theory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49702934/1218980).