# How to pass object data from parent to child components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to know how to make the contents object visible in the video.vue component.

This is the **Video.vue** components. This component is where I want to access the content object that is defined in the **Home.vue** component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
           title: 'Video Section'
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

This is the **Home.vue** component:

```
   <template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="column is-one-third" v-for="content in contents.results" :content="content" :key="content.id"> 
                <div v-show="loaded" class="loader"></div>
                <div class="card" >
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <figure class="image">
                            <img :src="imageUrl + content.backdrop_path" alt="Image">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left">
                                <figure class="image is-25x25">
                                    <img id="poster-image" :src="imageUrl + content.poster_path" alt="Image">
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-content">
                                <p id="movie-title" class="title is-4 no-padding">{{content.original_title}}</p>
                                <p><span class="title is-6"><i class="fas fa-star">{{" " + content.vote_average}}</i></span></p>
                                <p class="subtitle is-6"><i  class="fas fa-calendar-alt">{{" " + content.release_date}}</i></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            {{ content.overview }}
                            <div class="background-icon"><span class="icon-twitter"></span></div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="footer-card-icons">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
       export default{
          data: () => ({
            contents: [],
            baseurl: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3',
            apikey: '16667866c29ba1bc29e687b4892b8d5c',
            imageUrl: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280',
            loaded: true,
         }),

        created: function(){
           this.fetchData();
        },

        methods:{
          fetchData: function(){
            console.log('fetch data')
            this.$http.get(this.baseurl + '/discover/movie?api_key=' +
            this.apikey + '&sort_by=popularity.desc').then(response =>{
                this.contents = response.body;
                this.loaded = false;
            });
           }
        }
      }
 </script>
```

Comment: You could use [props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html), where you can either pass all the object properties or pass the complete object down.

Comment: I also [described communication channels in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49702934/1218980).

Comment: Can you give me a brief solution? Sorry for the question, is that I'm new using vue.js

Answer (score 2):

As Emile’s commented, you should use [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) in order to be able to pass data from parent to child component.

In your **Home.vue**, add:

`<videos :content=“contents”></videos>`

But if your `contents` data type is `Array`:

`<videos v-for=“content in contents” :key=“content.id” :content=“content”></videos>`

Notice that if you use `v-for` to loop a component, you need to add `key` attribute also.

Finally, in your **Video.vue**, you need to define the `props` like below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ content.overview }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
     props: [‘content’],
     data() {
       return {
           title: 'Video Section'
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

Remember, `props` are **reactive**. It will respond to any updates or changes in `content`.

UPDATE: It seems you have not properly declared your component. See [codepen link](https://codepen.io/josteph22/pen/KeZXeO). Better if you could declare any other components as **Single File Components** as explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

Comment: Regards,

I did everything that you proposed to me, but it shows an error in the component of Video.vue

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Can not read property 'overview' of undefined"

Comment: As for <video v-for = "content in contents": key = "content.id": content = "content"> </ video> I change it for Videos <Videos v-for = "content in contents": key = "content.id": content = "content"> </ Videos>

Comment: It means that the variable content is empty. Can you provide the console.log of contents after fetchData method ? For example, console.log(response.body).

Comment: Ok I believe there is something wrong with your http request. You are assigning this.contents with something empty in fetchData method.

Comment: I can show you the repository where I have the code, from github.?
Currently what I have is something very easy.

Comment: No problem. Just put the github link in your question.

Comment: https://github.com/ChrisMichaelPerezSantiago/TMDb-Hollywood-Content/blob/master/src/views/Home.vue

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue. [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/josteph22/pen/KeZXeO)

Comment: the only thing I want to do is to be able to access the array contents in the other components.

Comment: How do you declare Video.vue as component? There is no problem with your ajax request. By passing props, you can immediately use the props in that child component.

Comment: sorry for my innocence, could you show me an example with props if you were in Video.vue or Movie.vue?