# How can I communicate between sibling components easily in Vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

First off, I should say that I'm fairly new to Vue.js 2, but so far I love it. I'm using the latest version.

I have started to build my first bigger application but got into a situation right away, where I have a main `app` component and 2 different sibling components inside the app component.

```
<template>

    <div>
        <comp1></comp1>
        <comp2></comp2>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

    import Comp1 from './Comp1'
    import Comp2 from './Comp2'

    export default
    {
        components:
        {
            Comp1,
            Comp2
        },
        data: function()
        {
            return {
                
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Here is how Comp1 looks like:

```
<template>
    
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li @click="doClick(data)">Component 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    
    export default
    {
        data: function()
        {
            return {
                data: 123
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

...and here is Comp 2:

```
<template>
    
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Component 2: { newData }</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    
    export default
    {
        data: function()
        {
            return {
                newData: null
            }
        },
        methods:
        {
            doClick(data)
            {
                this.newData = data;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

What I would like to do is, fire the `doClick` event on **Comp1** and handle it on **Comp2**.

What's the most effective was and best practice to achieve the desired result? Do I need Vuex or just need to emit events somehow?

Comment: one approach is `<comp1 @click="$refs.comp2.doClick()"></comp1><comp2 ref="comp2"></comp2>`,  another approach is comp1 emit click event, then inside comp2, `this.parent.$on()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between sibling components in VueJs 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616167/communication-between-sibling-components-in-vuejs-2-0)

Comment: You have to think if the communication will happen between multiple components, if later on you are most likely to need a `Comp3` which needs to be aware of the events of the other two components, you should use Vuex. If the communication will only happen between those two components, you can go ahead and emit an event on Comp1, listen to that event in the parent component and change the data property which is used as a prop for Comp2.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of complicating stuff between `Comp1` and `Comp2` it's better to  just maintain the data in the parent component that holds the `Comp1` and `Comp2` instead. I will call this component `ParentComponent`.

This way you keep the real truth in one place. `Comp1` doesn't have to save the memory instead referenced the data given by `ParentComponent` through props and `Comp2` doesn't have to save the data saved by `Comp1` instead uses props too. Although small difference, if you use this consistently it will create a big difference. Now all you need is to use `emit` to announce that there's some interaction happens in `Comp1` or `Comp2`. This pattern is usually called **Smart and Dumb component** or some says "Smart and View" component.

Basically the "Smart" one manages all data and interactions while the "View" component just report to the Smart component. Now the benefit of this is that the "View or Dumb" component can be reused.

After all, if you save it in `Comp1` you have to save it in `ParentComponent` too, and then give it to `Comp2`. This means you have 3 data located instead of the earlier one where you have 1 data in `ParentComponent` that were being referenced by `Comp1` and `Comp2`.

Now while others mentioned Vuex, I think this is really an overkill thought. I do love the `Context` feature in React, and been waiting for it in Vue. It's like a smaller Redux or Vuex and turns out, that's all you need.

Now AFAIK Vue 2 doesn't have that. Maybe there's a similar package out there that can help you. But I won't say much about that, just google it. Feel free to share the package you find thought. I've been using React for the last 2 year, so I didn't have my knowledge updated.

Keeping your code simple is the best practice.