# Can i trigger function on another component from my header?

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, vuejs2

Hello i have a question about vue routing and how the tree works. I have my parrent router where i have my router-view and my header on same level.

i have some functions i want to trigger from my header to a route called dashboard within my router-view

e.g:
header.vue

```
<a href="#" @click.prevent="update()"> click me to update dashboard </a>
```

dashboard.vue

```
<p> {{datafrom filldata}} </p>

  methods: { 
   fillDataToP() {
    function to fill data
   }
  }
```

is this possible in vue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between sibling components in VueJs 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616167/communication-between-sibling-components-in-vuejs-2-0)

Comment: [Frank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952090/1218980) is one of the ways already listed in the duplicate candidate, there are other ways, and in this case, the data should be in a Vuex state and the update button should trigger an action which would update the state, then triggering a rerender of the dashboard accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the EventBus feature within vuejs.

in your `main.js` file add

`const EventBus = new Vue()`

`Vue.prototype.$bus = EventBus;`

from your `header.vue` file you can now emit an event:

Example `this.$bus.emit('someString', SomeObjectToPass);`

Then on your `Dashboard.vue` you can listen to an event by using:

`this.$bus.on('sameStringAsInEmit', () => {`

`// Fill Data`

`})`

Comment: When i create this it says that this.$bus.on is not an function

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the $ before on: this.$bus.$on() should work. Same goes for the emit: this.$bus.$emit() :)

Comment: hehe i figured that out, but now im trying to call a function from my methods on dashboard, but it says that the this.filldata() is not a function :)

Comment: i can console log things but not use a method from dashboard

Comment: The this, when calling this.filldata(), refers to the eventbus. What you could do is:
declare a variable called self and assign this to it (before you call the this.$bus). e.g var self = this;
Then in the .$on() you can use the method by calling it from the self:
self.functionToCallFromDashboard()