# Sibling component communication not working in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I am trying to send this.TC from typing.js to ending-page.js which are sibling components. Emits and event hubs not working. But emit from typing.js to parent works as I want. (There will be only one more call in this app, so i don't want use Vuex if it isnt necessary for this - i want to do it with simple emits ) Here's my code:

**Parent:**

```
      <template>
    <div id = "app">

    <typing v-if = "DynamicComponent === 'typing'" />
    <ending_page v-else-if = "DynamicComponent === 'ending_page'" />

    </div>
  </template>
  <script>

  /* Importing siblings components to parent component */
  import typing from './components/typing/index.vue'
  import ending_page from './components/ending-page/index.vue'

  export default {


    name: 'app',
    components: {
      typing,
      ending_page
    },

    data() {
      return {

        DynamicComponent: "typing",

      };
    },

    methods: {

      updateDynamicComponent: function(evt, data){

        this.DynamicComponent = evt;

      },

    },


  };

  </script>
```

**typing.js:**

```
      import { eventBus } from "../../main";

  export default {


    name: 'app',
    components: {

    },

    data() {
      return {

        /* Text what is in input. If you write this.input = "sometext" input text will change (It just works from JS to HTML and from HTML to JS) */
        input: "",

        /* Object of TypingCore.js */
        TC: "somedata",

        /* Timer obejct */
        timer: null,
        is_started: false,
        style_preferences: null,


      };
    },


      ICallThisFunctionWhenIWantToEmitSomething: function(evt) {

          /* Sending data to ending_page component */
          this.$root.$emit('eventname', 'somedata');

          /* Calling parent to ChangeDynamicComponent && sending TC.data what will be given to ending_page (I think it looks better with one syntax here) */
          this.$emit('myEvent', 'ending_page', this.TC.data);

        }

      },




  };
```

**ending-page.js:**

```
      import { eventBus } from "../../main";

  export default {
    name: 'ending-page',
    components: {},

    data () {
      return {
        data: "nothing",
      }
    },

    computed: {

    },

    props: {

    },

    methods: {


    },

    /* I know arrow functions etc but i was trying everyting */
    created: function () {
      this.$root.$on('eventname', function (data) {
          console.log(data)
          this.title = data
          this.$nextTick()
      })
    }

  }
```

Comment: PS: There's ABSOULETLY NOTHING in the console. Like $root.$on don't see any event.

Comment: Does `ICallThisFunctionWhenIWantToEmitSomething` actually get called?

Comment: Yes i checked it with console.log

Comment: ending-page sets `this.title`, but it doesn't _have_ a `this.title` in its `data`.

Comment: Its doesnt matter, i just copied important part of code, its pointless to paste here 400 lines. If it works it should show error or display data with console.log(data)

Comment: What you should do is write up an example that can be run to demonstrate the problem. I can emit on root and have another component receive it. There is no way to determine what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between sibling components in VueJs 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616167/communication-between-sibling-components-in-vuejs-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

It is an example of how to share data between siblings components.

Children components emits events to parent. Parent components send data to children.

So, the parent has the property `title` shared between the children. When `typing` emits
the `input` event the directive `v-model`capture it an set the value on parent.

Ref:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

https://benjaminlistwon.com/blog/data-flow-in-vue-and-vuex/

```js
Vue.component('typing', {
  props: {
    value: ''
  },
  template: '<button @click="emit">Click to change</button>',
  methods: {
    emit() {
      this.$emit('input', `changed on ${Date.now()}`);
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('ending-page', {
  props: {
    title: ''
  },
  template: '<div>{{ title }}</div>',
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'unchanged',
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <typing v-model="title"></typing>
  <ending-page :title="title"></ending-page>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking about that also. But isnt it x2 more waste of CPU?

Comment: Probably. Using frameworks is always a waste of resources.

Comment: Same pattern with angular: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

One can try communication using vuex,
the data you want to share make it on this.$store.state or if recalling for functions use mutation(sync functions) and actions(async functions)
https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I like what Jeffrey Way suggested once, just create a global events object (which accidentally can be another Vue instance) and then use that as an event bus for any global communication.

```
window.eventBus = new Vue();

// in components that emit:
eventBus.$emit('event', data);

// in components that listen
eventBus.$on('event');
```

Comment: EventBus concept was not supporting in vue3. Do you know, any alternatives