# Getting data from declared component in vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Currently trying to wrap my head around Vue and templates.

I read that you pass data from `child -> parent` with `$emit()`

> app.js

```
Vue.component('tweet-postbox', require('./components/tweetPostBox.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        addTweet (tweet) {
            //from the tweetPostBox.vue postTweet method
            console.log(tweet) 
        }
    }
});
```

> tweetPostBox.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="post-box">
        <div class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="profile-image rounded-circle"></div>
            <input v-model="message" type="text" id="tweetText" placeholder="Whats happening?">
        </div>
        <div class="controls d-flex align-items-center w-100">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" @click="postTweet" id="postTweet">Tweet</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                message: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            postTweet:  async function(){
            let response = await axios.post('/post', {
                message: this.message
            })
            //How to get this response data to the main vue instance?
            this.$emit('addTweet', response);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to get the value into my `app.js` from the component file... but nothing is console logged.  Where am I going wrong?

Update: Added HTML

```
<div class="container" id="app">
    <tweet-postbox></tweet-postbox>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you creating the `tweet-postbox` component? Using a template inside the element with id `app`, perhaps? You need to register the listener there. You'd need to use `v-on`, or the shorthand `@`, to listen for the event.

Comment: @skirtle I updated my question to show the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to change the template to:

```html
<div class="container" id="app">
    <tweet-postbox @add-tweet="addTweet"></tweet-postbox>
</div>
```

The `@add-tweet` part registers an event listener for the `add-tweet` event. I've used kebab case to avoid browser case-sensitivity problems. You'd need to emit the event with the same name, `this.$emit('add-tweet', response)`. See [the offical documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) to confirm that kebab case is the way to go.

The `="addTweet"` parts assigns the method `addTweet` as the listener.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Answer (score 0):

Found this great answer on another post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47004242/2387934

```
Component 1:

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    this.$root.$emit('eventing', data);

Component 2:
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    mounted() {
        this.$root.$on('eventing', data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I would not go anywhere near this code if I were you. It is not demonstrating simple parent/child eventing, it's a much more advanced technique for using `$root` in place of an event bus. You need to learn the basics from the official documentation first, [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) and [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

Comment: Well, is there an actual downside to using this?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, please fix your coding style, there's a lot of issues including indentation errors, try using `eslint` maybe.

Second, let's break `this.$emit('addTweet')` down a bit:

- `this` is in that line refers to the instance of the Vue component, thus an instance of `TweetPostBox`.
- When you call `$emit` with a `addTweet`, you're dispatching an event within the component.

Now that `addTweet` is dispatched, what's going to happen next? Vue is going to find all event handlers that handle `addTweet` and executes them.

Now in your case, you do not have any event handlers for this event. `addTweet` in your parent component is simply a local function in that component, it is not an event listener by any means.

To register an event listener, Vue provides `@` syntax, and you're already using that with `@click`, so just like you are doing `@click="dosomething"` (thus registering an event handler for `onClick` you need to use `@add-tweet`. (`@addTweet` also works but it is against coding style standards, Vue automatically handles the conversion for you)