# Vue sibling component communication not working for router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For my Vue 2.x app, I am trying to pass data from one sibling component to another sibling component via root Vue instance. I have applied the solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616167/communication-between-sibling-components-in-vue-js-2-0/47004242#47004242). But, it's not working for my app. It seems that data is not coming to the `ItemDetails.vue` component from `ItemList.vue` component properly.

**[Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bi2g4s)**

Comment: Why not using Vuex as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49702934/8816585 ?

Comment: The solution outlined in the linked answer only works if both components are mounted at the same time.

Comment: You don't need to emit events in this use case since you are using simple routing. You can add pass props through the router to another component. Here is your code with modification: https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-components-vuetify-forked-gwn3yq