# How to pass bata between siblings in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, shopping-cart

I'm creating a shopping cart in VueJS. I have the cart icon in the header and my products in another component. I need to take the array of products inside of the header so i can print the length near to the cart icon. Here some code:

```
data: () => {
    return {
        cart: [],
        products: [
            {
                name: "Margherita",
                price: 5,
                image: "https://www.scattidigusto.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/pizza-margherita-originale-Scatti-di-Gusto-1568x821.jpg"
            },
            {
                name: "Marinara",
                price: 4,
                image: "https://wips.plug.it/cips/buonissimo.org/cms/2012/05/pizza-marinara-5.jpg"
            },
            {
                name: "Diavola",
                price: 6,
                image: "https://www.coopshop.it/p/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Salame_940x450.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communication between sibling components in Vue.js 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616167/communication-between-sibling-components-in-vue-js-2-0)

Comment: You could either use [`this.$emit(...)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) to pass the data up to the parent, then back down the the sibling child using props. But a much better approach would be to use a Store (like [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)) to easily share data between components at any level

Answer (score 0):

You should store the list of products inside your Vuex store. From there the list will be available to each and every component in your application.

Comment: Vuex should not be a default. Understand how parent/child relationship works is more important actually.

Comment: The OP does not have a direct parent/child relationship - his Header component may be nested 2 levels away from the Root while his current `<router-view>` content might also have nested children. So learning why a shared store is needed in non-trivial applications is also important.